# subfloat and pgfplot with trim

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats

I am using subfloat and pgfplot to place two plots side by side. I want the subfloat caption to centre aligned with the axis so I use trim axis. But then my plots label goes out of the margin.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Fig 1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
        \begin{axis}[
            grid=major,
            scaled ticks=false,
            x post scale={0.8},
            y post scale={1.25},
            xmin=1,xmax=5,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.07,
            tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
            ylabel style={rotate=-90},
            xlabel={r},
            ylabel={$\displaystyle \frac{V_{test}}{V_{x}}$},
            legend cell align=left,
            legend entries={,$\Psi=0$,,$\Psi=2\pi$,,$\Psi=4\pi$}
        ]   

            \addplot [thick, blue] table [col sep=comma] {test.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\hfill
\subfloat[Fig 2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
        \begin{axis}[
            grid=major,
            scaled ticks=false,
            x post scale={0.8},
            y post scale={1.25},,
            xmin=1,xmax=5,
            ymin=0,ymax=0.07,
            tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
            ylabel style={rotate=-90},
            xlabel={r},
            ylabel={$\displaystyle \frac{V_{test}}{V_{x}}$},
            legend cell align=left,
            legend entries={,$\Psi=0$,,$\Psi=2\pi$,,$\Psi=4\pi$}
        ]   
            \addplot [thick, olive] table [col sep=comma] {test.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}   
\caption{Sample image}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Is it possible to fix it without specifying horizontal alignment in dimensions? Because it will be tedious as I have many plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `\hfill` width `\hfil`:

[image]

with this the bounding box are centered on page width, however the `y` labels aren't considered in centering (since with `trim axis left` are excluded).

Test code for above image is (your code snippet is unfortunately useless):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13, width=77mm}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% to show page layout

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\pgfplotsset{
    grid=major,
    scaled ticks=false,
    x post scale={0.8},
    y post scale={1.25},
    legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=south east
            }
    \centering
\subfloat[Fig. 1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$f(x)=x^2$}
            ]
\addplot {x};
\legend{$x$},
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
                }
    \hfil
\subfloat[Fig. 2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$f(x)=x^2$}
            ]
\addplot {x^2};
\legend{$x^2$},
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
                }
\caption{Sample image}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solutions adds extra space to the right of the `tikzpicture` to center the axis box rather than the bounding box.  It uses the `name=` option of axis to locate the edges.

The main difference between this and using `trim axis left` is when the plot gets too wide.  As you can see, it already forces the second subfloat to a new line.  I put frames around the subfloats to show their size.

Note: this is based on Zarlo's MWE.  I tried to use yours, but it really was useless.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13, width=77mm}

\newlength{\offset}
\newlength{\temp}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% to show page layout
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\pgfplotsset{
    grid=major,
    scaled ticks=false,
    x post scale={0.8},
    y post scale={1.25},
    legend cell align=left,
    legend pos=south east
            }
\centering\fbox{%
\subfloat[Fig. 1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[name=border,
ylabel={$f(x)=x^2$}
            ]
\addplot {x};
\legend{$x$}
\end{axis}
\pgfextractx{\offset}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{west}}%
  {\pgfpointanchor{border}{west}}}% \pgfpointorigin will do
\pgfextractx{\temp}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{east}}%
  {\pgfpointanchor{border}{east}}}% only about -0.2pt
\global\advance\offset by \temp
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{\offset}% add excess left margin to right
                }}%
\hfill\fbox{%
\subfloat[Fig. 2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[name=border,
ylabel={$f(x)=x^2$}
            ]
\addplot {x^2};
\legend{$x^2$}
\end{axis}
\pgfextractx{\offset}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{west}}
  {\pgfpointanchor{border}{west}}}%
\pgfextractx{\temp}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{east}}%
  {\pgfpointanchor{border}{east}}}%
\global\advance\offset by \temp
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{\offset}
                }}
\caption{Sample image}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: text area]